# Self join query: how to return children and parent row?

Tags: mysql, sql, self-join

I have this table:

```
Content:
- id
- parent_id
- slug
- creation_date
```

parent_id is a foreign key pointing to the same table (content.id).

I want to select all the rows in the table that are children of a parent_id in the same table. I would like the parent row to be returned too.

Right now I have these two queries, both of which work only returning the child rows:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM content a 
JOIN content b ON a.parent_id = b.id
WHERE b.slug = 'some-slug'
ORDER BY creation_date
```

and:

```
SELECT content.* 
FROM content 
WHERE content.parent_id = (SELECT id FROM content WHERE slug= 'some-slug')
ORDER BY creation_date
```

How can I return the child rows as well as the parent row ordered by creation_date?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you avoiding a `UNION` for some reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select  child.*
from    Content child
join    Content parent
on      child.parent_id = parent.id
where   parent.slug = 'some-slug'
union all
select  parent.*
from    Content parent
where   parent.slug = 'some-slug'
order by
        creation_date
```

Comment: Why are you using a subquery?

Comment: @Sonny: Good point, I was using it for the `order by`, but an `order by` applies to the entire union anyway. Updated the answer.